# Conditional logic case (x == (a || b))

Tags: c#, .net

Is there are a way to achieve the following in .net6:

```
if (x != (a || b)) { Do something }
```

for when `a` or `b` are not Boolean values?

Specifically a case when `x`,`a` and `b` are enums or numeric values like this:

```
enum Animal : byte {
    Cat,
    Dog,
    Cow,
    Dolphin,
    Horse,
    Whale   
}
```

Later we want to evaluate the state of a variable, lets say a user has to make a choice:

```
if (choice == (Animal.Dolphin || Animal.Whale)) {
        Console.WriteLine("Lives in the sea");
    }
```

I know this could be achieved with a `switch` statement but wondering if there is a way one can do it more compact like with a multi optional comparison inside an `if` statement.

Comment: I don't think you mean `x == (a || b)` I think you're looking for a DRY (_don't repeat yourself_) version of `(x == a) || (x == b)` Do I understand correctly?  If so, you can make an array of options like `array = new Animal[] { Animal.Dolphin, Animal.Whale }` and then ask `array.Contains(choice)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern matching with [`is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is):

```cs
if (choice is Animal.Dolphin or Animal.Whale)
{
    // ...
}
```

It also supports [negation patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns) (C# 9):

```cs
if (choice is not (Animal.Dolphin or Animal.Whale))
{
    // ...
}
```